# Batch file that runes SQL commands

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file that runs some SQL commands for example:
I'm signing in using these commands:

```
Sqlcmd -S <Server Location> -U <user> -P <password>
```

Next is going to be a backup for some database

```
BACKUP DATABASE <data base> TO DISK=<Location>
GO
EXIT
```

But after starting the .bat file, log in is successfully but the backup database is not working, I still need to type the commands.

There is a way to actually run those commands without typing in the commands?

Or should I try using something else, like Windows PowerShell?

Comment: `sqlcmd -i scriptfilename` should accomplish this - pu all of your required commands in `scriptfilename`.

Comment: @Magoo Hi, so basically I need another script that is running those commands, for example, another .txt? or .bat file? that have the commands that I want to run and have the same location of the .bat file with the commands

I say that just because on the .bat file I will have more than 5 commands that I want to run, 1: Stop the program, 2: sign in, 3: Backup, 4: start the program, the start - close are working well but the SQL part is messing me up.

Comment: As IUI, you simply create a text file containing the commands you would otherwise type, then execute those commands by issuing the `sqlcmd -i scriptfilename` command.

Comment: I tried to use the same method that you mention this is the error that I encounter :
https://imgur.com/a/cFJvAgd